# Sending a token via bep20 shows the wrong token on Metamask

Tags: javascript, web3js, metamask, bep20

When it goes to transfer, it shows the wrong token in the metamask

```
(async ()=>{
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractAddress);
    const transfer = await contract.methods.transfer(reciever, 1);
    const data = await transfer.encodeABI();
    if(window.ethereum.chainId == '0x61'){
        ethereum
        .request({
        method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
        params: [
            {
                from: ethereum.selectedAddress,
                to: reciever,
                gasPrice: '1000000',
                gas: '',
                data: data, 
        
            },
        ],
        })
        .then((txHash) => console.log(txHash))
        .catch((error) => console.error);
    } else {
        ethereum.request({ method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain', params:[{chainId: '0x61'}]})
    }
})()
```

It should show the token, but it shows differently,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When transferring tokens, the transaction needs to be processed by the contract address (not by the token receiver). Note that the contract receiver is passed as the first argument of the `transfer()` function.

Solution: Replace `to: reciever` with `to: contractAddress` in the `params` section of your snippet.